# 301 redirection using Apache's RewriteRule (for a Joomla website)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've got a problem with redirecting some page(s). My rewrite rule looks like that (example):

```
RewriteRule /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position$ article-keyword.html [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working, i was trying some different combinations but it still doing nothing.
Any solution?

Comment: Can you add some documentation on what you are specifically trying to accomplish?  From the rule you have posted, you appear to want to change a very specific URL `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position$` to `article-keyword.html`  If that is the case, is this redirection not taking place?

Comment: yeah I have several specific links which I would like to redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: The RewriteRule below is incorrect.  See update for 7/9/2012 for more details**

I have read that RewriteRules are always relative, therefore try:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position$ article-keyword.html [R=301,L]`
```

This should redirect `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position` to `article-keyword.html`

The `^` designates the beginning of the string.  Please take a look at http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html for more information on Apache's RewriteRule.

**Update - 2012-07-08**

Ok, after reading the Apache documentation, the RewriteRule DOES NOT match on the query string.  To match on data within the query string you need to use a `RewriteCond` and the `%QUERY_STRING` variable.

**Success! The following worked for me!**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ article-keyword.html? [R=301,L]
```

This redirected `http://site.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:article-keyword&catid=8:position` to `http://site.domain.com/article-keyword.html`

This only redirects requests to index.php that have the query string in question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still not redirecting, I've already tried that ^ at beginning, nothing helped.

Comment: Where are you placing this RewriteRule?  If in .htaccess, please post the entire .htaccess file.

Comment: I'm placing that right after RewriteEngine On statement and RewriteBase (also tried without setting RewriteBase).

Comment: I think the issue is that your literal string contains regex special characters that require escaping.  See this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) article on that.  These characters `.^$*+?()[{\ ` require escaping.  I am going to update my posting to include the requires escaping ('\').  Upon further review, the `?` definitely requires escaping `\?`.

Comment: Please post your .htaccess file so we can troubleshoot in more detail.  Perhaps something else in the file is interfering with the desired redirect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13626/discussion-between-kamil-and-heatfanjohn)

Comment: Actually, this isn't working for me either.  Let me play with it for a few minutes and I'll update you on what I find.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I have updated my answer with what worked for me.